# Sending email using perl with sendmail

Tags: perl, email

I am trying to send email using sendmail in perl. Email is sent but the content which I send as Subject gets added to 'To:' in the email. For example, if from address is `from@gmail.com`, To address is `to@gmail.com` and subject is `"test subject"`. I get the email with `Reply-to:` field as `from@gmail.com,"Subject:test.email","To:to"@gmail.com,"Content-type:text/plain"`

Here is my code:

```
     open(SENDMAIL, "|/usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t '$to_email' -f '$from_email'") || ($error_message .= "<P>Unable to open email process.</P>");
     print SENDMAIL $reply_to;
     print SENDMAIL $subject;
     print SENDMAIL $send_to;
     print SENDMAIL "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
     print SENDMAIL $content;
     close(SENDMAIL);
```

And if I remove $reply_to and $send_to lines, the email comes with `from:` field
as Apache server.

Any help would be appreciated. I do not want to use any other library like `Email::MIME` since it doesn't exist on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is wrong with what you show, but here is some working code

```
my ($header, $From, $To, $Cc, $ReplyTo, $Subject);

$From    = "From: $from";
$To      = "To: $to";
$Cc      = "Cc: $cc_addresses";
$ReplyTo = "Reply-To: $replyto";
$Subject = "Subject: $subj";

# Form the header.  The fields always submitted:
$header = join("\n", $From, $To, $ReplyTo, $Subject, '');

# Optional fields
$header .= "$Cc\n" if $cc_addresses;

open(SENDMAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t")
    or carp "Can't fork for sendmail: $!\n";
say SENDMAIL "$header\n$msg_cont";
close(SENDMAIL);
```

Note. There is `my $cc_addresses = '';` earlier, which then (possibly) gets built up.

Comment: I have tried the code which you have sent, but I get this error `No recipient addresses found in header`

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Comment: @v.coder  What I posted is right out of a library, with none of the variables actually defined -- did you fill that in?  I didn't make it complete since you posted only a fragment. I'll add to the post.

Comment: thanks it worked. the modified the order and seperated each field with '\n'. I think mine is old library, maybe that's the reason why it says recipient is missing. I added the same concern in question too.

Comment: @v.coder Ah, good.  That can be one of the problems with using `sendmail` directly -- along with possible changes during system updates. While this is still in use as a part of a library sub somewhere, it is better to build emailer using a module. In new code I use one with `Net::SMPT` (it is far better).