# How to use shell script code in a Perl script

Tags: shell, perl

I want to convert a shell script code in Perl and use exec to execute the code. I have program written in perl but on a condition i have to add a code which i know how we can do in shell script but not sure how we can do in perl.

Shell Script Code:

```
(
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Subject: "
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
cat <emailbody>
) | mailx -r "test@gmail.com"
```

My Perl Code:

```
!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $mailx = "/usr/bin/mailx";

if($ARGV[0] eq "ty" && $ARG[1]){
 /// Here we want to use the shell script code .
}

my @args_to_pass = ($mailx, @ARGV);
exec @args_to_pass;
```

Comment: There are a number of Perl modules for sending emails that you could use. Search around on metacpan for one that looks good.

Comment: @Shawn i know that. But i have some restriction under which i have to use this

Comment: Various versions of `mailx` exist, which differ (a lot) in how to specify headers.  Even `sendmail` is better (more consistent) -- can you use that instead?

Comment: @Developer : If you want to handle everything in shell, write it as a shell script, and invoke your script from your Perl application. This also makes debugging easier.

Comment: @zdim sendmail is also a good option i will try that as well.

Comment: "_sendmail is also a good option_" --- then how's [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459204/4653379), for example?  Something I could find readily.  There's a lot more on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A somewhat literal translation of your shell code would be:

```
if($ARGV[0] eq "ty" && $ARG[1]){
    my $pid = open(STDIN, '-|') // die "Can't fork(): $!";
    if ($pid == 0) {
        print "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        print "Subject: \n";
        print "Content-Type: text/html\n";

        exec 'cat', ... or die "Can't exec() cat: $!";
        # or print more text, but don't forget to exit() afterwards if you don't exec
    }
}
```

The idea is to create a pipe and a subprocess. Using [`open`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/open) as shown above does that, with the write end of the pipe connected to the child's `STDOUT` and the read end connected to the parent's `STDIN`.

The child process then writes data to the pipe and exits. It can do all the work by itself and `exit`, or `exec` into `cat` at the end.

All of the output produced by the child is available on the parent's `STDIN`, which is inherited by `mailx`.